GPS Signal Amplifier
I am completely new to RF. I am using this module in my design.I need to add a power amplifier for the GPS signal present in this IC.
This IC will be installed between this module and GPS antenna. The power amplifier selected by me is BGA524N6 from infineon.
The GPS frequency of the module is 1575.42 ±1.023 MHz.

My antenna circuit is given below.

May I know can I use the selected PA along with this module?
I think there is a mistake in our design.Please see the reference design from the vendor.

C4 is missing in our design.May be that is causing the trouble.Please confirm.

If you follow the design in the datasheet, then it should work, but at this frequency the layout is critical, so you need to accurately follow their guidelines. A much simpler solution is to get a GPS antenna with the amplifier built in: they're readily available and low cost.

Thank you.What are the parameters to be considered when selecting a GPS antenna with the amplifier built in.

Look for an 'active' antenna, check the gain & power requirements, and check that the Quectel module can provide that power down the antenna cable. If not, you'll need a 'bias tee' that feeds power into the cable. However, do be aware that adding an amplifier does not fix all GPS problems; for example, if you have an issue with the antenna picking up interference, the amplifier may not help.

I updated the question.If you don't mind could you please check.

If C4 is missing, no signal will get through. C1 R1 and L1 form a 'bias tee' to supply power to an active antenna. C4 carries the antenna signal into the module, but also blocks the antenna DC power from back-feeding into the module.

@jayben,May l know how C4 and L1 is calculated

I don't know, but would guess that C4 must be large enough to carry the GPS signal without significant attenuation, but small enough that it doesn't have significant inductance, which would block the signal. L1 is the opposite; it must be large enough so it blocks RF from going into the supply, but not so large (resistive) that it attenuates the DC signal.
